# Instagram API auth link not working on react-native webview

Tags: javascript, react-native, instagram-api, react-native-webview

I am trying to authenticate a user using a webview which loads the instragram auth api the link looks like this:
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1234&redirect_uri=https://redirect_url&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code&state=userGuid=123421

and i have configure my react-native webview like this:

```
<WebView
            onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
/>
```

this is showing me this error when the link loads:

[image: instagram link error result]

nothing happens when i click the login button as well.

i tried opening the same link on my Mac Chrome browser and it works fine, i tried adding the `userAgent` and `sharedCookiesEnabled` in hopes of mimicking a desktop browser but it doesn’t work, what am i missing here?